# PHP: regex for matching every single line

Tags: php, regex

I'm using an API which is checking values with php `preg_match` method. I can only use original value (I can't prepare it) and regex expression. Value is a multiple line string like

```
12 value;
13 value;
14 value;
```

Now I need to check if every line matches my regex expression which is for single line would be like `'/^\d+\s\w+\;$/'`.
So the correct regex would return `true` (1) for the previous value and false (0) for the value below:

```
12 value;
13 ;
14 value;
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include dotall modifier and then repeat the (*current pattern + newline char at the start*) zero or more times.

```
'/^\d+\h\w+;(?:\n\d+\h\w+;)*$/s'
```

In DOTALL mode, `^` matches the start of very first line. And `$` matches the end of very last line. And also I replaced `\s` with `\h` because `\s` will match all the spaces and also the line breaks. Though `\h` will also match single space and a tab , for an exact thing, include space only instead of `\h`

Comment: really, then there must be a need to edit the doc. See the markers in https://regex101.com/r/oC5rY5/7 and https://regex101.com/r/oC5rY5/8

Comment: My bad, misread that part. But the `/s` modifier has no effect on your regex, since it contains no `.`.

Comment: But it contains anchors.

Comment: So? Those aren't affected by `/s`: https://regex101.com/r/oC5rY5/7 vs https://regex101.com/r/gE5xQ7/2

Comment: ya, it also works without modifiers. But not with `m` modifier.

Answer (score 2):

```
^\d+\s\w+\;(?:\n\d+\s\w+\;)*$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/oC5rY5/5